# Save ListBox_SelectedItem to file.txt

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

HI all,
i wish save in a file.txt the chronology of the song played by my music Player .
I tried this code snippet but doesn't work :

```
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\Media PlayList\List.txt");

   private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        wmp.URL = Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem);

foreach (object o in listBox1.SelectedItems) 

         {
               sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - " + o.ToString());          
         }
    }
```

How i store songs :

```
private List<string> GetFolder(string Folder)
    {

        string filena;
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        List<string> str = new List<string>();

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            str.Add(file.FullName);    }
    }


private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       List<string> uno = GetFolder(@"D:\\Music\\");
        listBox1.DataSource = uno;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "uno"; }
```

I need each time the Music Player change song the file "List.txt" will be update by listbox.SelectedItem but i cannot update the "List.txt" with my code.
Where i wrong?
Thanks for your attention.

Nice regards

EDIT: I updated my code snippet hoping it will be clear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.DataSource = GetFolder("D:\\Music\\");
        }

        private static List<string> GetFolder(string folder)
        {
            List<string> FileList = new List<string>();
            foreach (FileInfo file in new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetFiles("*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                FileList.Add(file.FullName);
            return FileList;
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\Media PlayList\\List.txt", true);
            wmp.URL = Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            foreach (object o in listBox1.SelectedItems)
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - " + o);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will do the work for you. Notes:

- If you want to append to the file, you should pass true as the second argument when you create the StreamWriter.
- After writing your data to the file, you should explicitly close the StreamWriter, or your file will be empty.
- After closing the file you can no longer write to it. If you want you can reopen it.

Comment: HI  Jahedbozorgan,
that's work fine infact i wrong becasue i close the file and it was always empty ,with your cone snippet i work out the trouble.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If it's failing to *update* the file, you may wish to set the append parameter in the constructor, eg:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\Media PlayList\List.txt", true);
```

If it's failing to trigger the SelectedIndexChanged event, please update the question to reflect that...

Answer (score 1):

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
    wmp.URL = Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem);

    foreach (object o in listBox1.SelectedItems) 
           sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - " + o.ToString());          
   sw.close();
}
```